# [ReactJS MUI]Select autofocus to first MenuItem of same value

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

I have a select menu that contains a list of languages, in which the most commonly used ones are on top. Here is an example of what the code looks like:

```
<Select
  value={language}
  onChange={e => setLanguage(e.target.value)}
>
  <MenuItem value="Language 1">Language 1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 13">Language 13</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 41">Language 41</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 81">Language 81</MenuItem>
  <Divider/>
  <MenuItem value="Language 1">Language 1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 2">Language 2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 3">Language 3</MenuItem>
  ...
  <MenuItem value="Language 181">Language 181</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

What happens is that if the default value of Language is 81, here is what's selected:

```
<Select
  value={language}
  onChange={e => setLanguage(e.target.value)}
>
  <MenuItem value="Language 1">Language 1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 13">Language 13</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 41">Language 41</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 81">Language 81</MenuItem>
  <Divider/>
  <MenuItem value="Language 1">Language 1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 2">Language 2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 3">Language 3</MenuItem>
  ...
  <MenuItem value="Language 81">Language 81</MenuItem> <---
  ...
  <MenuItem value="Language 181">Language 181</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

and here is what I want to be selected:

```
<Select
  value={language}
  onChange={e => setLanguage(e.target.value)}
>
  <MenuItem value="Language 1">Language 1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 13">Language 13</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 41">Language 41</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 81">Language 81</MenuItem> <---
  <Divider/>
  <MenuItem value="Language 1">Language 1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 2">Language 2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Language 3">Language 3</MenuItem>
  ...
  <MenuItem value="Language 181">Language 181</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Is there any way to autofocus it on the most commonly used option rather than the one on the full language list?

Comment: I don't think you're really supposed to have the same value in the list multiple times. Is there any way you can omit the duplicates?

Comment: I could use a query for it, but that's just as a last resort.

Comment: Are you just manually populating all of these, or is there some kind of `map` going on? Maybe if you shared some more code around the context. I think the best bet is to try and omit  the duplicates if possible. I've been searching but I can't seem to find any documentation on the expected behaviour in HTML when a select has duplicate values!

Comment: I'm using a map for this actually, but I think that would be irrelevant to the behavior of the select button. Yeah, I couldn't find any either and just resorted to removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment,  I can't seem to find any documentation on the expected behaviour in HTML when a select has duplicate values.

I think your best bet is to **omit the options with duplicate values** to fix this problem, unless some light could be shed on what the expected behaviour is in that case, and how it could be controlled.